# In order to preallocate memory in Matlab, I want to initialize my array of objects. How do I do this?

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, memory-management

I have a class of objects known as blocks. Currently, I am creating an array of blocks using a for loop by simply tacking them unto an empty array

```
blockArray=[];
for ii=1:Size   
    blockArray=[blockArray block(....)];      
end
```

In order to preallocate memory, how do I initialize an object array of blocks with dummy values?

For instance if instead of using block objects I used numbers, I could easily preallocate by using zeros(1,Size). Is there something similar that I could do?

Answer (score 5):

The matlab documentation describes

> To preallocate the object array, assign the last element of the array first. MATLAB® fills the first to penultimate array elements with default DocArrayExample objects.

So, to do this, instead of iterating over from `1:size`, it is simpler to do...

```
blockArray = []
blockArray(size) = block(...)
```

Comment: Note that to do this, the constructor of your class needs to support a syntax with zero input arguments, which MATLAB will call in order to populate the first n-1 elements. So design your constructor by using `nargin` to test for the number of inputs, and supplying defaults if none are supplied.

Comment: I tried this using this way but I am getting the error: The following error occurred converting from block to double:
Error using double
Conversion to double from block is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The language does not really support this, there exists multiple solutions (or workarounds).

**Replicating the first instance**

When pushing the first element into the array, you can fill the whole array with this element to achieve a preallocation. This might look very bad, but it is actually the fastest possibility known to me.

```
for ii=1:S
    %assumption e is a scalar, otherwise the code is totally screwed
    e=block(....)
    if ii==1
       %to do preallocation, fill it with your first element
       blockArray(1:S)=e
    else
       blockArray(ii)=e
    end      
end
```

**Use cell arrays**

Obvious simple solution, you can put any class into the fields

```
blockArray=cell(S,1);
for ii=1:S
    %assumption e is a scalar, otherwise the code is totally screwed
    e=block(....)
    blockArray{ii}=e
end
```

This solution is very simple but slower than the first. You also lose some functionality which is not available for cell arras

**Let your class implement array functionality**

```
classdef A
properties
    arg1
    out
end
methods
    function  obj = A(varargin)
        if nargin==0
            %null object constructor
        elseif strcmpi(varargin{1},'createarray')
            sz=varargin(2:end);
            %preallocate
            obj(sz{:})=A;
        else
            %standard constructor
            obj.arg1=varargin{1};
            obj.out=[1 2 3;];
        end
    end

end
end
```

Constructor with no input argument creates an "empty" or "null" object, this is used to preallocate so it should be empty.
Constructor with first parameter `makearray` creates an array
Otherwise your constructor should be called.

Usage:

```
%create an empty object
A
%create an array of size 2,3,4
A('createarray',2,3,4)
%use the standard constructor
A(2)
```

Biggest downside is you have to modify your classes. Never tested this solution, but it should be close to the first in performance.